# How to take Statevector for subsystem?

Tags: qiskit, entropy, renyi-entropies

I want to calculate the 2nd Renyi entropy using the density matrix in Qiskit. To do this, I need to calculate the $Tr(\rho^2)$ for subsystem. The complete system consists of 12 qubits from which I want to choose a subsystem from two specific ones (for example, #3 and #5). I thought to use `qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector` but if there are other methods I will be glad to hear from you.

Here is my quantum state:

```
num_qubits = 12
measureZZ = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits,num_qubits)
measureZZ.h(0)
measureZZ.h(1)
measureZZ.h(5)
measureZZ.h(6)

measureZZ.cx(0, 2)
measureZZ.cx(1, 3)
measureZZ.cx(5, 7)
measureZZ.cx(6, 8)

measureZZ.cx(0, 3)
measureZZ.cx(1, 4)
measureZZ.cx(5, 8)
measureZZ.cx(6, 9)
  
measureZZ.cx(2, 5)
measureZZ.cx(4, 6)
measureZZ.cx(7, 10)
measureZZ.cx(9, 11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a subsystem could be entangled with the rest of the system and we can not describe it using a state vector. A general method that can be always used to describe the state of a subsystem is density matrix.

To get the reduced density matrix of a subsystem you can use [`partial_trace`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.partial_trace.html).

For example, to get the density matrix for 3<sup>rd</sup> and 5<sup>th</sup> qubits:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix
from qiskit.quantum_info.states import partial_trace

traced_over = list(range(0, num_qubits))
traced_over.remove(3)
traced_over.remove(5)

rho = DensityMatrix.from_instruction(measureZZ)
rho_3_5 = partial_trace(rho, traced_over)
```

Note that, in Qiskit you can use [`DensityMatrix.purity`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix.purity.html) to get $Tr(\rho^2)$

Comment: How do we get the subsystem statevector if we know that the state if separable? For example, if we run `Statevector.measure()` on some qubits, we know that the state will be separable wrt to these qubits.

Comment: You can get the density matrix of this subsystem using `partial_trace` as explained. Then call [DensityMatrix.to_statevector](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix.to_statevector.html)